# Laravel Log User Agent Data in Stack Trace

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I am currently using the default configuration for laravel error logging.

We are experience some errors on our production site which is logging information to a file. The full stack trace is in the file.

Is there anyway I can add user level data such as an IP address and User Agent to all stack traces? I imagine there's a way to extend the logging function, but I can't figure out where to look.

Comment: inside app/exception/handler.php there is "report" where you can put whatever you want to log

Answer (score 5):

Use this to add what you need to this to the `App\Exceptions\Handler.php` file.

```
<?php

namespace App\Exceptions;
use Exception;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Exceptions\Handler as ExceptionHandler;
class Handler extends ExceptionHandler
{

/**
 * Get the default context variables for logging.
 *
 * @return array
 */
protected function context()
{
    return array_merge(parent::context(), [
        'ip_address' => request()->ip(),
        'user_agent' => request()->header('user-agent'),
    ]);
}
```

This should add what you are looking for to all of your stack traces.

Comment: I should have included that I'm using laravel 5.2 which doesn't have the context() function available. This is good answer though, thank you.

Comment: I'll see if I can find and answer for you still

Answer (score 0):

As of 5.4 there is a discrete function to get the User Agent on the request object and global request function, so you can use `$request->userAgent()` or `request()->userAgent()` as a shorthand to the answer from Azeame.